# Angular does not apply global defined styles

Tags: css, angular, typescript, styling

Inside `styles.css` I defined the `mat-expansion-panel` to have the following margins

```
mat-expansion-panel {
    margin: 2vh;
}
```

However this won't be applied in my components unless it is specified in the local css file.

Even trying to import the `styles.css` from the component directive won't work

```
@Component({
  ...
  styleUrls: ['./list.component.css', '../../../styles.css']
})
```

as I will get the following error

```
./src/styles.css - Error: No template for dependency: CssDependency

Error: The loader ".../src/styles.css" didn't return a string
```

Comment: try to add like this  ::ng-deep mat-expansion-panel {
    margin: 2vh;
}

Comment: doesn't work. I also noticed that defined class are applied for `mat-card`s but not for `mat-expansion-panel`s

Comment: Angular does have a `global.css` file in the root. Try placing the style there. Every styled passed to component is scoped to the component only to emulate shadow dom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using the following in styles.css

```
.mat-expansion-panel {
    margin: 2vh !important;
}
```

But if you want to apply these styles to only one expansion panel, you can apply unique id or assign class to that particular expansion panel as well.

**EXPLAINATION**: whats happening is that angular material itself is adding margins on .mat-expansion-panel and this styling is overriding our custom styling. [!important](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/) increases importance([css-specifity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)) of a css rule.Thus, our rule overrides the default css.
[image]

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a1ancf?file=src%2Fstyles.scss)

Comment: check updated answer.  add !important with the css. I've also updated the stackblitz

Comment: using `!important` works, can you give me an explanation?

Comment: @AntonioSantoro you should check CSS specificity.  For reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: @AntonioSantoro sure i've updated my answer